# Getting the list of added networks in Android

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi

I couldn't find anything about this.

What I am after is scan the current available wireless networks and show the user only the ones that were added to phone. For instance person a is at home and can get 3 available networks but previously only added router x(so person a can connect to router x).

First approach that came to my mind was scan existing wi-fi networks and compare that with the previously added networks. I did the scanning existing wi-fi networks by using:

```
    List<ScanResult> sResults =  wifi.getScanResults();
    ArrayList<String> stringRes = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ScanResult result : sResults) {
        stringRes.add(result.SSID);
    }
```

but I couldn't find a way to get previously added network list. How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can get already added/configured networks.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
```